# How do I create objects to have different unique properties in derived classes in C# Windows Form,

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a banking app where I create an account number for a savings or checking account. I have an abstract Account class and a Savings and Checking class that inherits from it. When the an account is created it must be either a checking or savings account (this is done by a checkbox and a click button) so the account id assigned is unique to either checking or savings. The question is if I want to add if they are a college student or senior citizen (this is done by a checkbox) when they create an account this will be unique from just a regular checking or savings account. The purpose of adding this is so when I create an end of the month report accounts created for a college student or senior citizen will receive a lower monthly fee on their checking account and a higher interest rate on their savings account.

I am storing the account id in a list and "saccounts" is an object for the savings account class and "caccounts" is an object for the checking account class.

```
    private int _nextIndex = 0;
    List<Account> saccounts = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> caccounts = new List<Account>();
    private void createButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createNewAccount();

        clearFields();
    }
```

This is where the account is created. The use will check the checkbox for either checking or savings and an account is created and stored in List Account.

```
                if (checkingRadioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                _nextIndex++;
                transactionLabel1.Text = "Checking Account: #" + _nextIndex + " created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
                accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
                caccounts.Add(new CheckingAccount(balance)

                {
                    AccountID = _nextIndex
                });
            }
            else if (savingsRadioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                _nextIndex++;
                transactionLabel1.Text = "Savings Account: #" + _nextIndex + " created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
                accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
                saccounts.Add(new SavingsAccount(balance)

                {
                    AccountID = _nextIndex
                });
            }
```

This is how I have the Class setup.

```
    public abstract class Account  
    {

        public abstract int AccountID { get; set; }

    }
    class SavingsAccount : Account
    {
        private int accountId;
        private int senioraccountid;
        public override int AccountID { get; set; }
    }
    class CheckingAccount : Account
    {
        private int accountId;
        private int collegeaccountid;
        public override int AccountID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Yes if you read the title and the body the question is listed in both. The question is how do I create the account id to be unique when they are created when the use select they are a college student or senior citizen.

Comment: Nope...I am having issues with the words "created", "select",  and"unique". What do you mean, maybe try a user story.